# bibLaTeX: Custom \citep style

Tags: biblatex, citing

For days I’ve been messing around now with the otherwise great biblatex package but, alas, I am overwhelmed by all the technical mumbo-jumbo in its documentation. The thing I want to do is (hopefully) quite simple:

I want a citation with page-number and parentheses such as this one

```
``Some quote'' \citep[185]{author:book}
```

to look like this:

> “Some Quote” (Author 2001: 185)

I tried a number of citestyles but I never come even close to that, it always looks something like this:

> “Some Quote” (Author, 2001, 185)

Sorry for the probably dumb question but this menial detail is costing me a lot of nerves :(

Comment: Do you mean `\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}` and the `\textcite` and `\parencite` commands (assuming some sort of 'authordate' style)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you prefer to stick with `biblatex`, this is an easy modification (although it is true that the `biblatex` manual can be overwhelming at first [and second] glance).

Try this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}% ships with biblatex

\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

\begin{document}

% note: the 'natbib' option gives you access to natbib-like commands
``Some quote'' \citep[185]{doody}.
According to   \citet[33]{aristotle:anima}, \ldots.

% compare these:
``Some quote'' \parencite[185]{doody}.
According to   \textcite[33]{aristotle:anima}, \ldots.

% and \autocite
``Some quote'' \autocite[185]{doody}.
According to   Aristotle \autocite*[33]{aristotle:anima}, \ldots.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Note, if you are going to use `biblatex`, I recommend you also make use of `csquotes`, which was developed by the same package author.

Comment: Thanks! I think your MWE would benefit from loading standard `biblatex` and not `biblatex-chicago` (the latter does not support the standard way of loading bibliography and cite styles) though.

Comment: @moewe -- Oops!  Good point!  (Result of uncareful cutting and pasting....)

Comment: Wonderful and simple! I’d love to upvote your answer but I don’t have a big enough reputation around here, so I hope you get to read this comment. And I’ve already been using `csquote`. Thanks!

Comment: @PhilStrahl -- No worries.  I'm glad it was helpful!